# Grouping related information: Another table vs same table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table to store video information, like so:

```
-----------------
video
-----------------
video_id
title
description
duration
inserted_date
...
```

Many times, I have videos that are directly related to each other. For example, I have multiple videos of the same concert in small chunks of 5 minutes.
I want to be able to group those videos and give it a viewing position.

So when I'm viewing one video of the group I can easily display all of the other videos in the group (order by position) to the user.

I came up with this model, but since I'm not an expert on database modelling, I'm asking what is the appropriate model

```
-----------------
video
-----------------
video_id
title
description
duration
inserted_date
video_group
position
...
```

In my case, one video can be part of only one group and one group can have multiple videos.

Comment: Why do people take pleasure on voting down a legitimate question from someone who wants to learn. Don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need a table to keep the unique list of video groups.

So your videos table would be similar to what you have except that you would have a video_group_id instead of just video_group:

```
-----------------
video
-----------------
video_id
title
description
duration
inserted_date
video_group_id
position
...
```

And now you can create your video_group table to store all video_group details. Something like:

```
-----------------
video_group
-----------------
video_group_id
name
description
number_of_parts
total_duration
...
```